# how to get is_active_widget on active/runnning page? - wordpress function

Tags: wordpress, widget

I'm looking for a solution to check is_active_widget on particular page.
I got this https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/2302/loading-scripts-only-if-a-particular-shortcode-or-widget-is-present 
However the second way of sorich87 still loads the the scripts of a widget on every page where there's no certain active widget on the running/active page. Even when the sidebar of each page has different id & name.
For example:
I have page 'A' (with sidebar 'A1') which consists 'X' active widget and x_scripts in it.
Then when I check on page 'B' (with sidebar 'B1') which doesnt consist 'X' widget, it still loads the x_scripts of 'X' widget. Seems that this is_active_widget function only check for general activated widget, not on the running page.

This is my code:

```
class X extends WP_Widget
{
        function X(){
            $widget_ops = array('description' => 'X widget');
            $control_ops = array('width' => 200, 'height' => 500);
            parent::WP_Widget(false,$name='X-widget',$widget_ops,$control_ops);

            if ( is_active_widget(false, false, $this->id_base, true) ){
                add_action('wp_head', 'x_styles',0);
                add_action( 'wp_footer', 'x_scripts' );
            }
        }

    //rest of functions here
}
```

How to prevent this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it does, `is_active_widget()` get the value from options saved on database. Therefore it will return true for any widgets that is active. The `is_active_sidebar()` behaves the same, even though the sidebar is not loaded in specific pages, the returned value will always be true as long as the sidebar is registered.

Both functions check the global `$wp_registered_widgets`, `$_wp_sidebars_widgets`, `$sidebars_widgets` which values are generated from `register_sidebar()` and widgets that has been added to the sidebar.

Unfortunately, there's no workaround for this. Since `dynamic_sidebar()` is loaded after `wp_head()`, it's impossible to hook a script or stylesheet conditionally to it. The script or styles or anything you hook to `wp_head` will always there even the sidebar is loaded or not, unless widget is inactive.

Maybe, logically, a different possibility is there for adding a script on `wp_footer()` for a widget, in this case, you can set a global variable or define a constant in your widget function. Therefore, the scripts will be loaded only if widget is active.

Well, there's my two cents

Comment: Scripts should generally be placed at the end of the `<body>` anyway, unless there is good reason otherwise (scripts in the header slow down page load).  As of HTML5, CSS can also be placed at the end of `<body>` (now supported by WordPress but maybe wasn't when this answer was posted) though can result in layout glitches during page load.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to AriePutranto, who pushed me in the right direction. The same way you tell if there's an active widget in the `widget($instance)` function is how you decide whether to include your js/css files.

If you're fine with your includes being in the footer, then this works!

```
// Create the widget output.
    public function widget($args, $instance)
    {
        if (! empty($instance)) {
            add_action('wp_footer', array(&$this, 'enqueueWidgetIncludes'));
            $this->printWidget();           
        }
    }

    private function enqueueWidgetIncludes() {
        //css:

        wp_enqueue_style(/*[code removed]*/);

        wp_enqueue_script(/*[code removed]*/);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest solution to this problem would be to simply edit the sidebar widgets themselves. Just use `wp_enqueue_script()` & `wp_enqueue_style()` in the plugin files and it'll load them only on the pages where the separate widgets are displayed.